# What is the probability of two donuts picked are of the same type?

Tags: probability

A box contains two chocolate donuts, three cake donuts, and four sprinkle donuts. If two donuts are drawn from the box at random without replacement, what is the probability that the two donuts are of the same type?

Comment: What have you tried ? What is the Pr of drawing 2 chocolate donuts *without replacement* ? Can you not continue ?

Answer (score 2):

$Pr(\text{ 2 donuts of the same type }) = Pr(\text{ 2 chocolate donuts})+Pr(\text{ 2 cake donuts })+ Pr(\text{ 2 sprinkle donuts})=\dfrac{2}{9}\cdot \dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{3}{9}\cdot \dfrac{2}{8}+\dfrac{4}{9}\cdot \dfrac{3}{8}= \dfrac{20}{72}=\dfrac{5}{18}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It often helps when beginning to learn probability like this to draw yourself a [Tree Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_diagram_%28probability_theory%29).

[image: tree diagram]

Answer (score 1):

P(Ch) = $\frac2 9$ , P(Ca) = $\frac3 9$ , P(Sp)= $\frac4 9$

Ch, Ca and Sp, are used for Chocolate, Cake and sprinkle donuts.

Now, for X type of donut, where one donut has already been picked are, the changed Probability be P(X').

So, P(Ch') = $\frac1 8$, P(Ca') = $\frac2 8$, P(Sp') = $\frac3 8$.

$P(XX') = P(Ch) P(Ch') + P(Ca) P(Ca') + P(Sp) P(Sp')$

$= \frac29 * \frac18 + \frac39 * \frac28 + \frac49 * \frac38$
$= \frac5{18}$

Answer (score 0):

You can draw $2$ donuts out of the total $2+3+4=9$ donuts in $9\choose 2$$=9\times4  =36$ ways.

Now consider the specific criteria, that the two drawn donuts will be of same type.
So, these can be Chocolate donuts or cake donuts or sprinkle donuts.

Now, $2$ Chocolate donuts can be drawn from $2$ in $2\choose 2$$ =1$ ways, similarly, $2$ cake donuts can be drawn in $3\choose 2$$=3$ ways and $2$ sprinkle donuts can be drawn in $4\choose 2$$=6$ ways.

So the probability is $\frac {1+3+6}{9\choose 2}$$=\frac{10}{36}=\frac5{18}$